# zend pagination url format

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-paginator

i've followed the pagination tutorial from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html

I have successfully implemented pagination for my site, but i am not satisfied with the URLs output for the paging.  example url for page 2:

`http://www.example.com/posts/index/page/2`

What i would like is to remove the `index` and just have `http://www.example.com/posts/page/2`

Why is `index` included while accessing `this->url`(in the my_pagination_control.phtml from tutorial in link)?

Is there a way to gracefully just show `posts/page/2`? or even just `posts/2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that the previous answer is not enough, I'll give mine. First of all you can add a router in your `bootstrap.php` that looks like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
   protected function _initRoutes()
   {
      $Router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

      $Route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                      ':controller/*',
                      array(
                          'controller' => 'index',
                          'action' => 'index'
                      )
      );
      $Router->addRoute('paginator1', $Route);

      $Route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                      ':controller/:page/*',
                      array(
                          'controller' => 'index',
                          'action' => 'index',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'page' => '[0-9]+'
                      )
      );
      $Router->addRoute('paginator2', $Route);
   }

}
```

and then, use in your **view** this simple line:

```
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'CONTROLLER-NAME', 'page' => 5), 'paginator1', TRUE);
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'CONTROLLER-NAME', 'page' => 5), 'paginator2', TRUE);
```

In the case of 'paginator1', the url will be printed in this way:

```
/CONTROLLER-NAME/page/5
```

In the case of 'paginator2', the url will be printed in this way:

```
/CONTROLLER-NAME/5
```

Obviously where you see `CONTROLLER-NAME` will be the name of the controller you write.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
in your htaccess file

```
    
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Link for reference: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html
Hope it helps

Comment: so say i had MANY controllers with pagination and wanted to exclude `index` from each. is this still the desired way of excluding it?

Comment: @binnyb The advice to follow is to add routers.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa ah, excellent! i will now research how to use these.  thanks!